# convertPrice in smarty didn't work

Tags: smarty, prestashop-1.6

I would like to convert a price from euro to korona.
In the tpl, i  tried this

```
{convertPrice price=$product.prijs currency=$currencies.0.id_currency to_currency=false}
```

but the price is not changing, always showing the content of $product.prijs (price in euro)
Any help please.
PS: the content is displayed dynamically with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `displayPrice` in combination with the `convertAndFormatPrice` modifier, kinda like this:

```
{displayPrice price=$product.prijs|convertAndFormatPrice:$currencies.0.id_currency currency=$currencies.0.id_currency}
```

The first currency parameter is for the `convertAndFormatPrice` function and the second one is for `displayPrice`.